# dataLayer push limit

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

We have noticed that pushing via the dataLayer with a total of 3017 bytes or more, will result in our Google Analytics report not receiving that particular event.

For instance, our 'purchase' event with 12 product names in each 'item' object of the dataLayer, will be received by Google Analytics in the report, but only if the total bytes including the dataLayer are less than 3017 bytes.

There is no mention of this limit that we can find, and it would be great to actually track purchases of this amount. Our temporary procedure to track these is to push to the dataLayer every 3 products.

Any assistance or feedback would be appreciated as to a way around this.

Thanks!

Comment: please check if the enhanced eCommerce structure of your push is correct. https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce

Answer (score 0):

this is not a DataLayer limit but Google Analytics hit size limit.
Requests sent from your website (or app) to Google Analytics have a maximum size. Or, more specifically, the payload size (meaning the actual content body of the request) has a maximum.
This maximum size of the payload is 8192 bytes.
Read more about this and possible workarounds in [Simo's great arcticle](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/send-google-analytics-payload-length-as-custom-dimension/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although our request is well below the 8192 limit, we'll take a look at the article you provided. Thanks again, much appreciated.